# MS Access SQL: Adding two COUNT statements returns multiple copies of the sum instead of one

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm attempting to perform basic Arithmetic functions (+, -, *, /) between two different COUNTS.  In test runs, I have been about to get the query to return the sum of my two counts ("724") with the following statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(qryAttainment.[Attainment Samples Received]) 
          FROM qryAttainment 
          WHERE qryAttainment.[Attainment Samples Received]="On Time") +
       (SELECT COUNT(qryAttainment.[Attainment CofA Issued]) 
          FROM qryAttainment 
         WHERE qryAttainment.[Attainment CofA Issued]="On Time") AS [Test] 
  FROM qryAttainment
```

Unfortunately, it is returning 1240 rows all filled with the same number ("724").  How can I get it to just return a single row with the desired answer?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure what the edit did, but this revised code seems to still be outputting 1240 row copies of the sum of these two counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IIF(qryAttainment.[Attainment Samples Received]="On Time", 1, 0)) 
    +
    SUM(IIF(qryAttainment.[Attainment CofA Issued]="On Time", 1,  0))
 FROM qryAttainment
```

Comment: Regrettably, MS Access SQL does not seem to accept this syntax.  I received the following error: "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Comment: I'm afraid that it is still giving an error.  In this case, it says, "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect".  I see what you're trying to do though.  Perhaps MS Access SQL doesn't have a SELECT TOP function?

Comment: This is it!  Regrettably, Access SQL doesn't support CASE WHEN, but I am able to modify your statements appropriately to make them fit.

Now out of curiousity, why does COUNT not return only one line?  Does it have something to do with it being an "Aggregating" function?

Comment: Count does return 1 line, but in your original post you were selecting count as the definition of a column, but then had a FROM TABLE, so your 1 count was getting repeated for every row in the table.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I'd also be grateful for an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @BillGregg could you check the edit? Apparently need to use IIF rather than case when.